# React Native in desktop browser

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am currently reviewing different web/native technologies and I wonder if it is possible with React/React Native to build an application that can be as well rendered in a desktop browser as in the native device with React Native and if yes, what is the basic structure of such a website.

The idea behind this is to re-use the same display logic for browsers and native devices.

Comment: this may be of interest: https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web

Comment: Anything related to DOM and the browser in general is abstracted from the main `react` framework in a separate package called `react-dom`.  `react-native` is for native environments (think Android / iOS phones) what `react-dom` is for browsers.